# Exception when using String(byte[]) in Froyo for encoded string

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I just got this encoded binar file that has a custom estruture. To get the data out of it, I need to get certain blocos and just convert to string. I was using StringBuilder but it was breaking the UTF8. So I changed to this:

```
public String readString(int byteOffset, int byteCount) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[byteCount];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++) {
            buffer[i] = content[i + byteOffset];
        }
        String text = new String(buffer);
        return text;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        log(e.getMessage());
    }

    return "";
}
```

But, when I try to use the "new String(buffer);" I get an exception that jumps straight to return "";
Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Can you post the exception log (message and stacktrace)?

Comment: Ok, this was dumb of me... I moved the convertion and return to outside of the try/catch and it worked. Seem that my mistake was actually having a return inside the try catch...

Comment: No, having a return in a `try` block is not a problem.  The behavior you describ just means that your exception is occuring in the `for` loop.  I would wager that you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Nop... no exception message was presented. I fixed and even removes the try catch and works like a charm now...